# How can I regex match a single character that is not part of a pattern?

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

If I have a string like so:

`&#263;;
Joh&#263;; Smith <js@comms.com>;
;boom&#703;;woopwoop;
;`

and I wish to match all the semicolons that are not part of that html entity, what regex technique can I use?

I got close a couple of times with a negative look behind and my best attempt so far is the following:

```
(?<!&#.+?[^;]);
```

However this won't match all the semicolons required to take this victory home.

I'm using php.

I am considering replacing the html entities with a token first, then do the replacement of the semicolons and finally replacing the entities back into the string.

This seems quite clunky and inelegant so I'd rather do it with a regex, even if it gets a little unwieldy.

EDIT: @sln supplied a regex that will select nearly all entities, which as he points out should be the first step when trying to avoid something.

`(?i)[%&](?:[a-z]+|(?:#(?:[0-9]+|x[0-9a-f]+)));`

While the question is about how to select single characters except those found in a string, the context of the data I provided makes this a very useful regex to know and to attach to this question.

Comment: Is it in .NET? Btw, if you want to remove the semicolons, you may use `(&#\w+;)|;` and replace with `$1`

Comment: I'm afraid not, it's in php.

Comment: So, it is easier - `'~&#\w+;(*SKIP)(*F)|;~'` - and replace with whatever you wanted. See https://regex101.com/r/ZhITR4/1

Comment: Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Wow. Yes. That was fast! Thankyou very much :) Sorry to be a pain but will you pop this in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: entity (?i)[%&](?:[a-z]+|(?:#(?:[0-9]+|x[0-9a-f]+)));

Comment: That is interesting, matches all the encoded entities. Thankyou @sln.

Comment: @plumpNation - And why avoid matching a general pattern. What you want to avoid is first and foremost. Without that being correct, the entire regex is invalid for your purposes.

Comment: Sorry for being slow, could you elaborate please @sln? First match the pattern you want to avoid, then figure out how to reverse?

Comment: Sure. The general pattern you're trying to _avoid_ was `&#\w+;` As you can see from my regex, it's far removed from being a entity pattern. What's the result? It not only misses the majority of entities, it matches text that are not entities, skipping right over the `;` you'd want to match. It is the gorilla in the room.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation.

Comment: I see what you mean. I have created this https://regex101.com/r/ZhITR4/3 with your example. However my example may be incorrect, I made a smaller version here to show where it seems to fail. https://regex101.com/r/ZhITR4/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match and skip the entity and match the semi-colon in all other contexts:

```
$s = preg_replace('~&#\w+;(*SKIP)(*F)|;~', 'NEWTEXT', $s);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZhITR4/1)

**Details**:

- `&#\w+;` - a `&#`, followed with 1+ word chars and a `;`
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - two PCRE verbs that fail the current match and proceed looking for the next match after the text matched
- `|` - or
- `;` - a semi-colon.